# find command not giving any output

Tags: shell-script, awk, find, variable

Please anyone know why this command is not giving me any output? allthe variables are correct but no result.

```
find . -name "$cdr_type*$DAYZ*.unl*" |
  xargs zcat |
  awk -F "|" '{if($14==$tdate && $22==$misdn) print $0}'|
  head
```

When I echo the command like this

```
echo "find . -name $cdr_type*$DAYZ*.unl* | xargs zcat | awk -F | '{if($14==$tdate && $22==$misdn) print $0}'|head"
```

here is my output:

```
find . -name mgr*20160928*.unl* |
  xargs zcat |
  awk -F | '{if(4==20160928093911 && 2==2348094398953)}'|
  head
```

My observation is its showing $4 and $2 instead of $14 and $22

Comment: Try `${ cdr_type}`, `${DAYZ}`, `${14}` and `${22}`
  instead of `$cdr_type`, `$DAYZ`, `$14` and `$22`.

Comment: How do you _echo_ it? `$14` as expanded by the shell would be the same as `${1}4` and if `$1` is empty, that would give `4` as expected. In there, it looks like there are some `$`s that you want to pass untouched to `awk` and some for which you want shell variables to be expanded.

Comment: echo "find . -name $cdr_type*$DAYZ*.unl* | xargs zcat | awk -F | '{if($14==$tdate && $22==$misdn) print $0}'|head"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$14` when expanded by the shell in most Bourne-like shells is the same as `${1}4`, and if `$1` is empty or unset, that gives `4` as expected. Here you want to pass a litteral `$14` to `awk` so that `awk` treats it as its 14th field.

Normally within single quotes, that `$1` variable would not be expanded but you're not telling us how you *echo* that command.

In any case, here, it looks like you want:

```
find . -name "$cdr_type*$DAYZ*.unl*" -exec zcat {} + |
  awk -F "|" -v tdate="$tdate" -v misdn="$misdn" '
   $14 == tdate && $22 == misdn' |
 head
```

That is pass the content of  the `$tdate` and `$misdn` shell variables as `awk` variables.

Comment: This worked, just what I wanted!!! Thanks!